# Remove all SyntaxTrivia nodes from Roslyn SyntaxTree

Tags: c#, syntax, formatting, roslyn

I am trying to remove all nodes of type `SyntaxTrivia` from a `SyntaxTree` using Roslyn.

I tried to use the `SyntaxRewriter` class, but that does not work as `SyntaxTrivia` is non-nullable:

```
public class WhitespaceRemover : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
   public override SyntaxTrivia VisitTrivia(SyntaxTrivia trivia)
   {
       // Cannot convert null to 'SyntaxTrivia' because it is a non-nullable value type
       return null;
   }
}
```

What's the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried `return default(SyntaxTrivia);`?

Comment: I'm sure that you want to rewrite a `SyntaxNode` invoking `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNodeExtensions.WithoutTrivia(...)` on it, not a `SyntaxtTrivia`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Well. That makes sense. Please make it an answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: To give some more credit here, @Christian.K's suggestion works for removing trivia tokens that are not attached to a syntax node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you need to rewrite a `SyntaxNode` invoking `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNodeExtensions.WithoutTrivia(...)`, which will removes all trivias, instead of try to rewrite a `SyntaxtTrivia`.

Upd. @Emiswelt correctly mentioned that should override `Visit` method and additionally overriding `VisitTrivia` in the comment, which allows to remove non atached trivias from `SyntaxTree`

You can use it inside your syntax rewrite and it will looks like this:

```cs
public class WhitespaceRemover : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode Visit(SyntaxNode node) => base.Visit(node).WithoutTrivia();

    public override SyntaxTrivia VisitTrivia(SyntaxTrivia trivia) => default;
}
```

Comment: The correct method to override is `Visit`, `base.Visit(...)` needs to be called, and `VisitTrivia` also needs to be overriden to return an empty SyntaxTrivia token. With all that in mind, it works and strips all white space.